# Intellij IDEA maven remote repositories error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[hello, has anyone experienced this on Intellij IDEA? I couldn't find any solutions to this, I'm using mac and I already installed maven using sdkman, but it is showing this error even if I try updating this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbpda.jpg)

Comment: Show us the error from the idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file. Most likely, something like your proxy or antivirus/firewall is preventing IDE from making connections to a remote Maven repository.

Comment: Hello Andrey, thank you for your help, but It stops detecting error for no reason after I updated it. I'm thankful for your response.

Answer (score 0):

That's an error I faced a few years ago.

Try to disable
File -> Settings -> Maven -> Importing -> "Use maven3 to import project"

[The issue was discussed here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102693)

Or if it's not that, then share some more info like errors or the maven tab options.

Comment: Thank you for helping, i just left it updating and it stopped detecting error for no reason. Still, thank you so much for your response :)

Comment: That's great! Keep going :)

Comment: In the 2022.1.2 Build this is now located under Settings -> Buil, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven
Maven Home Path (and use your installation folder instead of Maven 3 [by default])